# Upload running test report to bitbucket

Tags: team-city

I have an automation testing project hosted on bitbucket and teamcity cloud server who running it. The automation testing project will generate a test report dynamically with timestamp name and this need upload to bitbucket.

Questions: How to dynamically upload the test report to bitbucket after running the test project?

Comment: I don't think this is a SQA type of question. Look for GIT on SO.